# FSSpec Error Handling in Python - Timeout Error

Tags: python, timeout, spatial, fsspec

I am trying to get Terraclimate Data from Microsoft Planetary and facing time out error. Is there a possiblity of increasing the timeout time ? Please find the code below and the error I am facing. I am using fsspec and xarray for downloading spatial data from MS Planetary portal.

```
import fsspec
import xarray as xr

store = fsspec.get_mapper(asset.href)
data = xr.open_zarr(store, **asset.extra_fields["xarray:open_kwargs"])
```

---

```
clipped_data = data.sel(time=slice('2015-01-01','2019-12-31'),lon=slice(min_lon,max_lon),lat=slice(max_lat,min_lat))
```

---

```
parsed_data = clipped_data[['tmax', 'tmin', 'ppt', 'soil']]
        lat_list = parsed_data['lat'].values.tolist()
        lon_list = parsed_data['lon'].values.tolist()
        filename = "Soil_Moisture_sample.csv"
        for(i,j) in zip(lat_list,lon_list):
                parsed_data[["soil","tmax","tmin","ppt"]].sel(lon=i, lat=j, method="nearest").to_dataframe().to_csv(filename,mode='a',index=False, header=False)
```

I am getting the following error

```
  TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\fsspec\asyn.py:53, in _runner(event, coro, result, timeout)
         52 try:
    ---> 53     result[0] = await coro
         54 except Exception as ex:
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\fsspec\asyn.py:423, in AsyncFileSystem._cat(self, path, recursive, on_error, batch_size, **kwargs)
        422     if ex:
    --> 423         raise ex
        424 if (
        425     len(paths) > 1
        426     or isinstance(path, list)
        427     or paths[0] != self._strip_protocol(path)
        428 ):
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:455, in wait_for(fut, timeout, loop)
        454 if timeout is None:
    --> 455     return await fut
        457 if timeout <= 0:
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\fsspec\implementations\http.py:221, in HTTPFileSystem._cat_file(self, url, start, end, **kwargs)
        220 async with session.get(url, **kw) as r:
    --> 221     out = await r.read()
        222     self._raise_not_found_for_status(r, url)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py:1036, in ClientResponse.read(self)
       1035 try:
    -> 1036     self._body = await self.content.read()
       1037     for trace in self._traces:
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py:375, in StreamReader.read(self, n)
        374 while True:
    --> 375     block = await self.readany()
        376     if not block:
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py:397, in StreamReader.readany(self)
        396 while not self._buffer and not self._eof:
    --> 397     await self._wait("readany")
        399 return self._read_nowait(-1)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py:304, in StreamReader._wait(self, func_name)
        303     with self._timer:
    --> 304         await waiter
        305 else:
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py:721, in TimerContext.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
        720 if exc_type is asyncio.CancelledError and self._cancelled:
    --> 721     raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
        722 return None
    
    TimeoutError: 
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    FSTimeoutError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [62], in <cell line: 3>()
          1 # Flood Region Point - Thiruvanthpuram
          2 filename = "Soil_Moisture_sample.csv"
    ----> 3 parsed_data[["soil","tmax","tmin","ppt"]].sel(lon=8.520833, lat=76.4375, method="nearest").to_dataframe().to_csv(filename,mode='a',index=False, header=False)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py:5898, in Dataset.to_dataframe(self, dim_order)
       5870 """Convert this dataset into a pandas.DataFrame.
       5871 
       5872 Non-index variables in this dataset form the columns of the
       (...)
       5893 
       5894 """
       5896 ordered_dims = self._normalize_dim_order(dim_order=dim_order)
    -> 5898 return self._to_dataframe(ordered_dims=ordered_dims)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py:5862, in Dataset._to_dataframe(self, ordered_dims)
       5860 def _to_dataframe(self, ordered_dims: Mapping[Any, int]):
       5861     columns = [k for k in self.variables if k not in self.dims]
    -> 5862     data = [
       5863         self._variables[k].set_dims(ordered_dims).values.reshape(-1)
       5864         for k in columns
       5865     ]
       5866     index = self.coords.to_index([*ordered_dims])
       5867     return pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(columns, data)), index=index)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py:5863, in <listcomp>(.0)
       5860 def _to_dataframe(self, ordered_dims: Mapping[Any, int]):
       5861     columns = [k for k in self.variables if k not in self.dims]
       5862     data = [
    -> 5863         self._variables[k].set_dims(ordered_dims).values.reshape(-1)
       5864         for k in columns
       5865     ]
       5866     index = self.coords.to_index([*ordered_dims])
       5867     return pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(columns, data)), index=index)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.py:527, in Variable.values(self)
        524 @property
        525 def values(self):
        526     """The variable's data as a numpy.ndarray"""
    --> 527     return _as_array_or_item(self._data)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\variable.py:267, in _as_array_or_item(data)
        253 def _as_array_or_item(data):
        254     """Return the given values as a numpy array, or as an individual item if
        255     it's a 0d datetime64 or timedelta64 array.
        256 
       (...)
        265     TODO: remove this (replace with np.asarray) once these issues are fixed
        266     """
    --> 267     data = np.asarray(data)
        268     if data.ndim == 0:
        269         if data.dtype.kind == "M":
    
    File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\dask\array\core.py:1696, in Array.__array__(self, dtype, **kwargs)
       1695 def __array__(self, dtype=None, **kwargs):
    -> 1696     x = self.compute()
       1697     if dtype and x.dtype != dtype:
       1698         x = x.astype(dtype)
    
    File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\dask\base.py:315, in DaskMethodsMixin.compute(self, **kwargs)
        291 def compute(self, **kwargs):
        292     """Compute this dask collection
        293 
        294     This turns a lazy Dask collection into its in-memory equivalent.
       (...)
        313     dask.base.compute
        314     """
    --> 315     (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
        316     return result
    
    File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\dask\base.py:600, in compute(traverse, optimize_graph, scheduler, get, *args, **kwargs)
        597     keys.append(x.__dask_keys__())
        598     postcomputes.append(x.__dask_postcompute__())
    --> 600 results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
        601 return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
    
    File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\dask\threaded.py:89, in get(dsk, keys, cache, num_workers, pool, **kwargs)
         86     elif isinstance(pool, multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
         87         pool = MultiprocessingPoolExecutor(pool)
    ---> 89 results = get_async(
         90     pool.submit,
         91     pool._max_workers,
         92     dsk,
         93     keys,
         94     cache=cache,
         95     get_id=_thread_get_id,
         96     pack_exception=pack_exception,
         97     **kwargs,
         98 )
        100 # Cleanup pools associated to dead threads
        101 with pools_lock:
    
    File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\dask\local.py:511, in get_async(submit, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally, pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, chunksize, **kwargs)
        509         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
        510     else:
    --> 511         raise_exception(exc, tb)
        512 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
        513 state["cache"][key] = res
    
    File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\dask\local.py:319, in reraise(exc, tb)
        317 if exc.__traceback__ is not tb:
        318     raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
    --> 319 raise exc
    
    File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\dask\local.py:224, in execute_task(key, task_info, dumps, loads, get_id, pack_exception)
        222 try:
        223     task, data = loads(task_info)
    --> 224     result = _execute_task(task, data)
        225     id = get_id()
        226     result = dumps((result, id))
    
    File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\dask\core.py:119, in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
        115     func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
        116     # Note: Don't assign the subtask results to a variable. numpy detects
        117     # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
        118     # operations in-place.
    --> 119     return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
        120 elif not ishashable(arg):
        121     return arg
    
    File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\dask\array\core.py:128, in getter(a, b, asarray, lock)
        123     # Below we special-case `np.matrix` to force a conversion to
        124     # `np.ndarray` and preserve original Dask behavior for `getter`,
        125     # as for all purposes `np.matrix` is array-like and thus
        126     # `is_arraylike` evaluates to `True` in that case.
        127     if asarray and (not is_arraylike(c) or isinstance(c, np.matrix)):
    --> 128         c = np.asarray(c)
        129 finally:
        130     if lock:
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py:459, in ImplicitToExplicitIndexingAdapter.__array__(self, dtype)
        458 def __array__(self, dtype=None):
    --> 459     return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py:623, in CopyOnWriteArray.__array__(self, dtype)
        622 def __array__(self, dtype=None):
    --> 623     return np.asarray(self.array, dtype=dtype)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\indexing.py:524, in LazilyIndexedArray.__array__(self, dtype)
        522 def __array__(self, dtype=None):
        523     array = as_indexable(self.array)
    --> 524     return np.asarray(array[self.key], dtype=None)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\zarr.py:76, in ZarrArrayWrapper.__getitem__(self, key)
         74 array = self.get_array()
         75 if isinstance(key, indexing.BasicIndexer):
    ---> 76     return array[key.tuple]
         77 elif isinstance(key, indexing.VectorizedIndexer):
         78     return array.vindex[
         79         indexing._arrayize_vectorized_indexer(key, self.shape).tuple
         80     ]
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\zarr\core.py:788, in Array.__getitem__(self, selection)
        786     result = self.vindex[selection]
        787 else:
    --> 788     result = self.get_basic_selection(pure_selection, fields=fields)
        789 return result
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\zarr\core.py:914, in Array.get_basic_selection(self, selection, out, fields)
        911     return self._get_basic_selection_zd(selection=selection, out=out,
        912                                         fields=fields)
        913 else:
    --> 914     return self._get_basic_selection_nd(selection=selection, out=out,
        915                                         fields=fields)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\zarr\core.py:957, in Array._get_basic_selection_nd(self, selection, out, fields)
        951 def _get_basic_selection_nd(self, selection, out=None, fields=None):
        952     # implementation of basic selection for array with at least one dimension
        953 
        954     # setup indexer
        955     indexer = BasicIndexer(selection, self)
    --> 957     return self._get_selection(indexer=indexer, out=out, fields=fields)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\zarr\core.py:1247, in Array._get_selection(self, indexer, out, fields)
       1241 if not hasattr(self.chunk_store, "getitems") or \
       1242    any(map(lambda x: x == 0, self.shape)):
       1243     # sequentially get one key at a time from storage
       1244     for chunk_coords, chunk_selection, out_selection in indexer:
       1245 
       1246         # load chunk selection into output array
    -> 1247         self._chunk_getitem(chunk_coords, chunk_selection, out, out_selection,
       1248                             drop_axes=indexer.drop_axes, fields=fields)
       1249 else:
       1250     # allow storage to get multiple items at once
       1251     lchunk_coords, lchunk_selection, lout_selection = zip(*indexer)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\zarr\core.py:1939, in Array._chunk_getitem(self, chunk_coords, chunk_selection, out, out_selection, drop_axes, fields)
       1935 ckey = self._chunk_key(chunk_coords)
       1937 try:
       1938     # obtain compressed data for chunk
    -> 1939     cdata = self.chunk_store[ckey]
       1941 except KeyError:
       1942     # chunk not initialized
       1943     if self._fill_value is not None:
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\zarr\storage.py:717, in KVStore.__getitem__(self, key)
        716 def __getitem__(self, key):
    --> 717     return self._mutable_mapping[key]
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\fsspec\mapping.py:137, in FSMap.__getitem__(self, key, default)
        135 k = self._key_to_str(key)
        136 try:
    --> 137     result = self.fs.cat(k)
        138 except self.missing_exceptions:
        139     if default is not None:
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\fsspec\asyn.py:111, in sync_wrapper.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        108 @functools.wraps(func)
        109 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        110     self = obj or args[0]
    --> 111     return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
    
    File ~\Anaconda3\envs\satellite\lib\site-packages\fsspec\asyn.py:94, in sync(loop, func, timeout, *args, **kwargs)
         91 return_result = result[0]
         92 if isinstance(return_result, asyncio.TimeoutError):
         93     # suppress asyncio.TimeoutError, raise FSTimeoutError
    ---> 94     raise FSTimeoutError from return_result
         95 elif isinstance(return_result, BaseException):
         96     raise return_result
    
    FSTimeoutError:
```

Comment: Please forgive the indentation. I am facing some error while doing the same.

Answer (score 3):

In the line:

```
store = fsspec.get_mapper(asset.href)
```

You can pass extra arguments to the fsspec backend, in this case HTTP, see fsspec.implementations.http.HTTPFileSystem. In this case, `client_kwargs` get passed to `aiohttp.ClientSession`, and include an optional [`timeout`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientTimeout) argument. Your call may look something like

```
from aiohttp import ClientTimeout
store = get_mapper(asset.href, client_kwargs={"timeout": ClientTimeout(total=5000, connect=1000)})
```

Comment: This was previously the accepted answer, but no longer. May I ask why?